# Add context sensitive help to UI components such as a GEF/Draw2d figure

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-gef, draw2d

As a tooltip can just provide less hints,we decide to add F1([context sensitive](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/ua_help_context.htm)) help to the UI components such as a draw2d figure.But facing a problem that: we can't find suitable positions and parameters to invoke the method `IWorkbenchHelpSystem.setHelp(Control control, String contextId)`.

Now we do a workaround like this:

```java
//in UserDefinedEditPart
@Override
protected IFigure createFigure() {
    //set help... (FIXME)   
    PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getHelpSystem().setHelp(Display.getCurrent().getActiveShell(), PublicConstants.CONTEXT_ID);
    return new UserDefinedFigure();
}
```

As you see,`setHelp()` method' first parameter should be a SWT or JFace Control,but it was set to be the the current workbench.I think a figure in draw2d is lightweight and has not be associated with anything about SWT or JFace.

Thanks for solution advice.

Answer (score 0):

The widgets of SWT and draw2d are quite different from each other. SWT just provides a platform to draw2d, where something "can be drawn". Hence, for SWT, there is no way to differentiate between a draw2d Label, or say a draw2d Connection. All it understands is that something by a "Figure" (which may have any number of figures as it's children) will be painted in some specified area (painted, that's it, no semantics to it).

You may have a look at the **org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.PopupDialog** class. May be you can make a custom help Dialog (it is not too difficult to extend) with extending this class.